# PHP-FPM creating files as root when configured as www-data

Tags: permissions, users, docker, root, php

In a multiple-container Docker application deployed with `docker-compose` I have a container built from alpine running PHP-FPM. That container is used both for providing PHP to the Nginx container, but also to run PHP scripts *on the container* from a CLI command *on the host*. Files created by PHP when run from CLI commands on the host are owned by `root` (UID 0), and have the `root` group (GID 0), even though FPM is configured to use the user `www-data` (UID 1000) and group `www-data` (GID 1000).

Here are the relevant parts of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine
RUN echo http://dl-2.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/ >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk --no-cache add shadow && usermod -u 1000 www-data && groupmod -g 1000 www-data
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
```

Here is the configuration:

```
$ docker-compose exec php grep -E "user|group" /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
user = www-data
group = www-data

$ docker-compose exec php grep www-data /etc/passwd
www-data:x:1000:1000:Linux User,,,:/home/www-data:/sbin/nologin
```

And here is a demonstration of the fine problem:

```
$ docker-compose exec php ./artisan make:model Foo -m
Model created successfully.
Created Migration: 2020_09_25_051836_create_foos_table

$ docker-compose exec php ls -ln /var/www/html/database/migrations/2020_09_25_051836_create_foos_table.php
-rw-r--r--    1 0        0              571 Sep 25 05:18 /var/www/html/database/migrations/2020_09_25_051836_create_foos_table.php
```

I had also tried prefixing the run command with `env UID=1000 GID=1000` as suggested in some forums, however that had no effect. Thinking that maybe the CLI interpreter (`/usr/local/bin/php`) might not use FPM behind the scenes, I tried checking for PHP config that may be relevant but found none:

```
$ docker-compose exec php grep -rvE "^; " /etc/php7/ | grep "user\|group"
/etc/php7/php.ini:;user_ini.filename = ".user.ini"
/etc/php7/php.ini:;user_ini.filename =
/etc/php7/php.ini:;user_ini.cache_ttl = 300
/etc/php7/php.ini:;ignore_user_abort = On
/etc/php7/php.ini:;syslog.facility = user
/etc/php7/php.ini:user_dir =
/etc/php7/php.ini:;user_agent="PHP"
/etc/php7/php.ini:;odbc.default_user  =  Not yet implemented
/etc/php7/php.ini:;ibase.default_user =
/etc/php7/php.ini:mysqli.default_user =
```

**How can I configure PHP to write files as user `www-data`, i.e. UID 1000?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "user" in the docker compose yml file and specify the userid:groupid

```
user: "1000:1000"
```

Comment: Thank you Sandeep!